# Partial molar volume and constant composition

Tags: thermodynamics

Why is it necessary that the composition of a mixture (with 2 components A and B) remains constant to arrive at this equation

$$
\begin{aligned} V &=\int_{0}^{n_{A}} V_{\mathrm{A}} \mathrm{d} n_{\mathrm{A}}+\int_{0}^{n_{\mathrm{B}}} V_{\mathrm{B}} \mathrm{d} n_{\mathrm{B}}=V_{\mathrm{A}} \int_{0}^{n_{\mathrm{A}}} \mathrm{d} n_{\mathrm{A}}+V_{\mathrm{B}} \int_{0}^{n_{\mathrm{B}}} \mathrm{d} n_{\mathrm{B}} \\ &=V_{\mathrm{A}} n_{\mathrm{A}}+V_{\mathrm{B}} n_{\mathrm{B}} \end{aligned}
$$

where $V_{\mathrm{A}}$ is the partial molar volume of component A.

$$
V_{\mathrm{J}}=\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial n_{\mathrm{J}}}\right)_{p, T, n^{\prime}}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Start from mathematics. Consider a property $P$ that depends on parameters $x_j$. The total derivative of $P$ can be written as below.

$$ dP = \sum_j\ \left( \frac{\partial P}{\partial x_j}\right)_{x_k \neq x_j} dx_j $$

Each partial derivative in the summation holds all $x_k$ constant *except* $x_j$.

Let's set $P$ as the total volume of a system $V$. It is an extensive property, meaning that it depends on the total amount of material present. The $x_j$ are the parameters $T, p$, and the total moles of each component $n_j$ in the system. We therefore find the following:

$$ dV = \left( \frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_{p, n_j} dT + \left( \frac{\partial V}{\partial p}\right)_{T, n_j} dp + \sum_j \left( \frac{\partial V}{\partial n_j}\right)_{T, p, n_k \neq n_j} dn_j$$

Allow that we work at constant temperature and pressure. The first two terms vanish. Allow that we simplify this for a binary solution. We therefore end with the following:

$$ dV_{T,p} = \left( \frac{\partial V}{\partial n_A}\right)_{T,p,n_B} dn_A + \left( \frac{\partial V}{\partial n_B}\right)_{T,p, n_A} dn_B$$

This equation does not demand that composition remain constant. It only requires constant temperature and pressure.

We define partial molar volume as

$$\breve{V}_j = \left( \frac{\partial V}{\partial n_j}\right)_{T,p, n_k \neq n_j} $$

The above equation for a binary becomes

$$ dV_{T,p} = \breve{V}_{n_A} dn_A + \breve{V}_{n_B} dn_B$$

Since $n_B$ is constant in the partial molar volume of A and $n_A$ is constant in the partial molar volume of B, we can integrate each term individually.

$$ V_{T,p} = \int_o^{n_A} \breve{V}_{n_A} dn_A + \int_o^{n_B}  \breve{V}_{n_B} dn_B$$

The first integral physically says, make a mixture by adding component A to a system with an existing amount of moles of B *while keeping the moles of B constant*. The total volume depends on how A mixes in to B. The corresponding picture holds for the second integral.

Partial molar volume may depend on the instantaneous composition of the mixture. Indeed it typically does. In a binary mixture, one approach is to write the partial molar volume as a function of what is considered as the solute (the minority component). For example, assuming that B is the solute, one might write a polynomial expression in the mole fraction of B as this:

$$ \breve{V}_B = \bar{V}_B(1 + a (1 - x_B) + b (1 - x_B)^2 + \ldots) $$

At pure B ($x_B = 1$), the partial molar is the molar volume.

Finally, a physical sense of the meaning of partial molar volume might be obtained by considering two different larger scale types of mixtures. First, consider a case where you mix ping pong balls and tennis balls. The two "molecules" are nearly the same size. The volume that you obtain will typically be about what you would expect when you would mix comparable amounts of either pure ping pong balls or pure tennis balls. By comparison, mix soccer balls and marbles. Here, the marbles are smaller and can fill the holes between the soccer balls. The volume of mixing is not the same as when you mix either pure soccer balls or pure marbles.

The first case is a system where the partial molar volumes of the two components are nearly equal to each other and to their pure molar volumes. The second case is one where the partial molar volumes of each component are not the same and are not the same as the pure component molar volumes.

To appreciate that partial molar volume is not constant with composition, consider that when you have added enough of the marbles, the holes between the soccer balls are filled. After that point, the marbles will start pushing apart the soccer balls instead of just filling the holes. At the start then, for marbles being added to pure soccer balls, the partial molar volume of marbles in soccer balls is nearly zero. By a certain amount of marbles, the partial molar volume of marbles being added to soccer balls is positive and greater than zero.

Attractive and repulsive interactions between molecules can have a comparable affect on partial molar volume. The forces act to pull or push the existing molecules, causing a smaller or larger molar volume increase.

Comment: That was really helpful. But i cant see how can $\frac{d V_{A}}{d n_{A}}$ and $
\frac{d V_{B}}{d n_{B}}$ be constant when the composition does not remain constant. For example, in a container there are 2 components A and B with a specific mole ration. When an amount of A is added to the solution the composition is changed which leads to change in intermolecular force between a molecule with the surrounding molecules.

Comment: Let's say A exerts a stronger pulling force compared to B so the addition of A to the solution wouldn't result in a big increase in volume compared to addition of B. Keeping concentration of B constant while adding more A to the solution would mean that a molecule will be surrounded more by A. Hence $
\frac{d V_{A}}{d n_{A}}
$ will change with each addition of A.

Comment: @Jung I've expanded my explanation to try to address your question.

Answer (score 0):

The  composition of the mixture  $V_a$, $V_b$  don't need to remain constant
$V_A$ can vary  from  small  to  big, and also  $V_B$, $n_A$ and $n_B$,

but $\frac{dV_A}{dn_A}$ and  $\frac{dV_B}{dn_B}$   need to  be constant
so that

$dV_A$ and $dV_B$   can  be replaced by  $V_A\cdot dn_A$  and  $V_B\cdot dn_B$ after the first  two integral signs.

A more  exact  treatment  is given  on Pg4 of
http://showard.sdsmt.edu/MET320/Handouts/Solution_Thermo.pdf
Howard  2001

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary for the composition of a mixture to be constant for that equation to be derived.  That equation is always true.  But, the derivation is simpler if we recognize that, for a constant composition mixture, the partial molar volumes of A and B, which are intensive properties, are constant.  For a derivation of the relationship (which is also applicable to all extensive properties, and not just volume) not requiring that assumption, see Smith and van Ness, Introduction to Chemical Engineering Thermodynamics.